# GPO not being applied

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have a GPO to add a icon/exe shortcut for Forticlient to users desktop thats not working. (Forticlient is installed by a separate GPO).

In User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Shortcuts

[image: oup]

The permissions are to allow all authenticated users:

[image]

In an effort to isolate the issue I was able to do the exact same procedure in a VM Windows Server and it worked as expected (test domain).

In a further effort to isolate the issue I created a new user on the original domain that was not working, and logged on with this test user - the icon was created.

gpresult shows the policy applied to the new user but not the existing users.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

The problem it turns out is to do with the folder redirection for the user.

[image]

I do not however know how to setup this GPO shortcut with folder redirection.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the "Common" tab (FortClient Properties) ?
Did you launch gpresult as an administrator ? (you shouldn't)

Comment: Please show us the delegation tab, and the advanced section of it. You could have a configuration where authenticated users is shown under security filters but a more granular deny rule could be applied in the before mentioned tab. This is by design.

EDIT: Of course, I'm talking about a deny acl like "deny apply"